# How to boost performance EF Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework

I use asp.net 4 c# and EF 4.

I'm profiling my application. I have this code which result expensive.

I woud like to know if you know a better way to write it. I need to speed it up.

```
            string htmlhead = context.CmsOptions.SingleOrDefault(op => op.OptionId == 7).Value;
            if (htmlhead != null)
                uxHtmlHead.Text = htmlhead;
            else
                uxHtmlHead.Text = "No Html Head.";
```

Thanks

Useful article
http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2010/09/20/which-one-is-faster-singleordefault-or-firstordefault.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault()` ... This will exit as soon as it finds a result.

On the other hand `SingleOrDefault()` searches the entire collection for a single result and throws exception if it finds more than one result for the query

Comment: Thanks, I did some test and FirstOrDefault seems faster: SINGLEORDEFAULT
stopWatch.Elapsed = {00:00:02.5203217}
FIRSTORDEFAULT
stopWatch.Elapsed = {00:00:00.5238185}

Comment: One more point..You should use `FirstOrDefault()`, when you are sure that the collection contains only one or none. Incase the collection contains more than one, you will never know, as it won't throw any exception as in case of `SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: Not sure the previous version, in EF6 it uses select top 2 for SingleOrDefault and if it returns 2 records it throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

There are some basic steps you can take when optimizing an Entity Framework query.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx) you can find a list of all the options.

The ones I would suggest in your case are:

- NoTracking. You only retrieve the entity for getting a value. Not for changing it so you don't need change tracking
- Precompile your query. This is an easy step and it really gives you a performance boost
- Return the correct amount of data. You are selecting a whole entity just to retrieve it's value property. If you would only select the Value property less data will be returned from SQL Server (BTW, your code will throw a Null Exception if a CmsOption can't be found because of the First/Single -OrDefault part. If you really know there should be at least one entity remove the OrDefault part)

If you are using Visual Studio Premium you could put this code in a Unit Test and then profile the unit test. After each change you can compare the reports to make sure you are improving performance.

Comment: Thanks Wouter, I implemented NoTracking, but in my case how could I return the correct amount of data? Do you know a better way to write the code? Please suggest me a sample.. Thanks!.ì

Comment: Shall I use an AnoymouseType instead??? like:                 var htmlhead = context.CmsOptions.Where(op => op.OptionId == 7).Select(x => new { x.Value });
                uxHtmlHead.Text = htmlhead.ToString();

Comment: Yep! That would be the correct way. If you check with SQl profiler you will see this will result in selecting only one field instead of the whole row.

Comment: I follow your advice here an example of my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267331/ef-pre-compile-query-and-return-of-a-scalar-value maybe you can be me and additional advice :-)